# Javascript and jQuery not secure over https

Tags: javascript, jquery, https

I am building an ASP.NET MVC 3 app which will run in Azure. Everything was working well, until I switched to https. Now most of my jQuery plugins and some other javascript are not secure.

I'm using the Datatables library as well as jsTree, Watermaks and Breadcrumbs. Most of this script is to make our site look appealing.

Is there a way to make this secure? Or is it time to move a very lean javascript site?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by `insecure`? Do you load js from your site, using the same https protocol, or do you load them from external resources?

Comment: I was loading jquery from a CDN through http, not https.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just load your scripts via `https` instead of `http` ... seems obvious enough.

If you are loading them from a CDN, check if said cdn has a `https` option, if not, you'll need to serve them yourself through the same `https` protocol you are using for the rest of your site.

Comment: Ya, that was the solution.. totally just missed the s! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm probably just being a stickler, but HTTPS is slower than HTTP. It'd be better to use HTTP when possible.

Comment: @KyleMacey I don't think anyone would suggest using HTTPS unnecessarily, but loading assets over http on a https site breaks the SSL verification.

Answer (score 10):

The jQuery site itself does not support https:// as a host. My suggestion is to download the latest version and host it yourself with a relative path (eg. `/js/jquery.js`) so it will match your protocol. As a side note, removing the protocol from the beginning of an absolute path will match the protocol that the user is browsing in. Like so:

`<script src="//www.google.com/someresource.js"></script>`

will link to either http or https depending on the current url the user is browsing.

Comment: Also this question probably belongs moreso in Webmasters. Not really a programming question by definition

Comment: Thanks for the help! Duly noted about the placement of this question